# Undefined class constant 'PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT'

Tags: php, pdo, fluentpdo

I'm using PHP FluentPDO, this query works in localhost, but not in webhosting. PHP version is 7.4, FluentPDO: `"envms/fluentpdo": "^2.2"`:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$mysql['db_name']};host={$mysql['host']}", $mysql['user'],
    $mysql['password'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'", PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$q = new Query($pdo);

$q->from('table')
    ->where(['email' => 'admin@example.com'])
    ->select('id, name, email, password', true)
    ->fetchAll();
```

The error is:

> Undefined class constant 'PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT'

Comment: Please do not do this `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"`. This is deprecated for the past 10 years and it will cause you problems. Set the `utf8mb4` charset in the DSN instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PHP version is 7.4

This PHP version is no longer supported. Please upgrade to an actively supported version if you can.

[`PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) is available only since PHP 8.0.7, so if you are using an earlier version, this constant will not be available.

FluentPDO version 2.2 should still support PHP 7.4, which makes this a bug in FluentPDO. There already exists a [pull request](https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo/pull/327) to fix this bug.

Answer (score 1):

This package seems to have a configuration error. Current stable version declares PHP/7.1 as minimum version ([code](https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo/blob/v2.2.3/composer.json#L19)):

```
"php": ">=7.1",
```

However it's using the `PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT` constant, which requires PHP/8.0.7 or greater ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.fetch-default) and [code](https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo/blob/v2.2.3/src/Queries/Base.php#L43)):

> `PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT` (int)
> Specifies that the default fetch mode shall be used. Available as of PHP 8.0.7.

```
/** @var int */
protected $currentFetchMode = PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT;
```

Your options are:

- Report the issue and hope it's fixed by maintaining backwards compatibility with your PHP version. **Edit:** https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo/issues/326
- Upgrade to a supported PHP version.
- Find another library.